# Is it possible to redirect to a Url instead of adding in shop cart?

Tags: affiliate, referral

I would like to make this optional. Like some of the products are able to be added in shopping cart and some of some when a user click on add to cart it sends him to the referral store.

Is there any extensions doing this ? any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: which Magento version are you using?

Comment: @ImranSheik ver. 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

A module with exactly this requirement I do not know. You can add an attribute to your products. With this you can control what is output in the front end. So it is simply possible to replace the AddToCart button with a link. The link you can also create as a separate attribute.

Comment: In fact I'm not an expert in magento and I'm looking for the easiest way. If you can provide me an example for something similar it would be great.